Limes of series of polygons with $\leq M$ edges also has $\leq M$ edges
Suppose in the following, all polygons are $C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R}^2)$. If the series of polygons $(P_n)_{n\geq 1}$ with all having $\leq M$ edges for $M\geq 1$ is (uniformly) convergent to the limes polygon $P\in C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R}^2)$, it seems clear that $P$ also has $\leq M$ edges. However, I am not able to prove it strictly.
I tried using convergence of the vertices of the $P_n$ but since two different "vertex-series" can converge towards the same vertex in $P$ it gets quite confusing for me to prevent a single vertex-series converge to two different new vertices for $P$. While this intuitively instantly violates uniform convergence due to an edge of $P_n$ becoming two non-collinear edges in $P$, it is hard for me to write it down properly.

$P_n$ is a function $[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$ with the property that there are $t^n_0=0\leq t^n_1\leq\dots \leq t^n_{M+1} = 1$ such that $P_n$ is linear on $[t^n_i, t^n_{i+1}]$ for $i=0,\dots,M$ and $P_n(0) = P_n(1)$. We wish to show that $P$ has the same property. This is clear if all the $t_i^n$ were the same for all $n$, so we reparametrize to reduce to this case. By passing to a subsequence we may assume that $t_i^n$ is convergent for $i=0,\dots,M+1$, say $t_i^n\to t_i$ as $n\to\infty$. Let $\varphi_n:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be such that $\varphi_n(\frac{i}M)=t_i^n$ for $i=0,\dots,M+1$ and interpolate linearly between $\frac iM$ and $\frac{i+1}M$. Similarly define $\varphi$. Since the $t_i^n$ converge as $n\to\infty$ it is easy to see (by writing out explicitly the linear function) that $\varphi_n\to \varphi$ uniformly as $n\to\infty$. Let $\tilde P_n:=P_n\circ\varphi_n$ and $\tilde P=P\circ\varphi$. Then for $t\in[0,1]$ we have\begin{align*}
|\tilde P_n(t)-\tilde P(t)|&=|P_n(\varphi_n(t))-P(\varphi(t))|\\
&\leq|P_n(\varphi_n(t))-P(\varphi_n(t))| + |P(\varphi_n(t))-P(\varphi(t))|
\end{align*}
Now using that $\varphi_n\to\varphi$ uniformly, $P$ being uniformly continuous and $P_n\to P$ uniformly, it follows that $\tilde P_n\to \tilde P$ uniformly (pointwise suffices for our argument). Every $\tilde P_n$ is linear on $[\frac iM, \frac{i+1}M]$, so the same holds for $\tilde P$. This implies that $P$ is linear on $[t_i, t_{i+1}]$: If $t_i=t_{i+1}$ this is clear and if $t_i\ne t_{i+1}$, $\varphi\rvert_{[\frac i M,\frac{i+1}M]}$ is injective and we can write $P\rvert_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}=\tilde P\circ \varphi\rvert_{[\frac i M,\frac{i+1}M]}^{-1}$ which is linear.
